# Broadcom Cooperation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY Driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, dell, broadcom

I need a Broadcom Cooperation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY Driver

Please note:
I have no ethernet card, and my Ubuntu laptop has no internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Go here [b43.zip](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117874)

Download the b43 zip file to a flash drive then drag and drop the file to your ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Open a terminal and do:

`sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43`

`sudo cp Desktop/b43/* /lib/firmware/b43`

`sudo rmmod -f b43`

`sudo rmmod -f ssb`

`sudo modprobe b43`

if you have not installed any other wireless driver your wireless should now be working.