# Wireless and Ethernet, both are not working in Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dell

I have installed Ubuntu (12.04/12.10) as dual boot with windows 7 on Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop.
In Ubuntu's both version, network connection is not detected for wireless and Ethernet while on Windows OS, it is working fine.

I checked for **bcm43 kernal drivers**, those are also not default installed.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me, when I had wifi problems on a dell recently:

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
>
> sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

Here is my question
 [How do I get WiFi working on my Dell Inspiron 1501?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322598)